# Programmatically turn on/off Action Center

Tags: c#, notifications, registrykey

Is there a way to programmatically turn on/off the Action Center?  Additionally, I'd like to know if there is a way to programmatically turn on/off specific notifications?  In manufacturing we use a base image of Windows 10 that has them turned off, and I am working on a patch to an application we make.  One of the things I have been tasked with is turning them back on with my patch (or at least figuring out of it is NOT possible).

I don't need to know how to do Toast Notifications.  I just need to make the Action Center visible, and turn on notifications for Windows Updates and Defender

Comment: posted a bounty - looking specifically for answers to programmatically turning on Windows Update & Defender notifications in Action Center when they are currently off.

Answer (score 6):

You set the `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer]` `"DisableNotificationCenter"` key to `dword:00000000`

```
Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer", "DisableNotificationCenter", 0, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

**Then to enable Defender notifications:**

```
Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\UX Configuration", "Notification_Suppress", 0, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

**I'm not sure exactly which notification you are trying to enable regarding Windows Update.**

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that one around, but even if that does work it doesn't cover my additional need to be able to turn on the Windows Update notifications or Defender notifications.

Comment: @sshoots See update.  Not sure which update notification you are looking to enable.

Comment: Haven't looked at the Defender notifications, but more interested in the Windows Update ones. Have systems with NoAutoUpdate=1 and Action Center Windows Update notifications set to off - so user is not informed of updates via 2 different methods. Turning NoAutoUpdate=0 is easy enough but users are still not notified due to Action Center notifications being off. Looking to script enabling notifications of windows updates for thousands of systems.